# LicensesDialog NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, jar

I want to use the [LicensesDialog library](https://github.com/PSDev/LicensesDialog). I downloaded JAR from that page and included it in my project, but when...

```
new LicensesDialog(ExpenseDetailsActivity.this, R.raw.notices, false, false).show()
```

...is called I get errors:

```
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at de.psdev.licensesdialog.NoticesXmlParser.parse(NoticesXmlParser.java:35)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at de.psdev.licensesdialog.LicensesDialog.<init>(LicensesDialog.java:51)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at com.shopility.activity.PreferencesActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(PreferencesActivity.java:217)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onMenuItemSelected(Watson.java:119)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlock.java:603)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:78)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:205)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:964)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:514)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:99)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
11-20 10:12:17.773: E/AndroidRuntime(7713):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried to include `simple-4.1.2.jar`, but that didn't fix this error. Any ideas how to avoid that?

Comment: Author here: I have updated the library to remove almost all dependencies (simple-xml and commons-io).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.Mark all checkboxes.Click on Apply and clean the project.

This worked for me.

Comment: After this error disappeared. Then i had similar problem with missing library `commons-io.jar`. At the very end dialog started to display but it was still buggy. I think something is wrong with the LicensesDialog jar, but it's probably better to post this in another question.